# How come this MongoDB update doesn't work?

Tags: mongodb, database

```
db.posts.update({}, {"pop_score":999});

db.posts.find({},{"pop_score":1});
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4d8eadd6df83500f3b000004"), "pop_score" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4d8eb1e3df83500f3b000035"), "pop_score" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4d8eb238df83500f3b000039"), "pop_score" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4d91377bdf8350063d000000"), "pop_score" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4d913c19df8350063d000001"), "pop_score" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4d8eacabdf83500f3b000000"), "pop_score" : 1 }
```

I update the pop_score to 999, for all posts.  But when I query for them, it didn't update.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It did work, but only updates the FIRST matching document by default.  I suspect you have SOME document in there that is now 999.

What you need to do is to tell MongoDB to update *every* matching document, by setting the optional `multi` flag to true:

```
db.posts.update({}, {"pop_score":999}, false, true)
```

This will update every document rather than just the first it finds.

You may wish to review the [docs on updating](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating) as well which have more info on these flags.

Answer (score 2):

Beware that update() **replaces** the found element with the one passed as argument, you should use the `$set` atomic operator to update a field's value (and of course, Brendan is right about the first vs. multiple match):

```
db.posts.update({}, { $set: { pop_score: 999 } }, false, true)
```